# How do you produce one static library for both release/debug on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

I would like to release a static library similar to what PayPal did (https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep) for the iPhone.  They were successful in incorporating both the release/debug version of their static libraries into one single *.a file. I have found solutions to combine simulator/device static libraries but not combining release/debug libraries without causing a collision on platform. (http://blog.costan.us/2009/12/fat-iphone-static-libraries-device-and.html)   Does anyone know how to produce a library that combines the release and debug versions of a static library?

Comment: Please open a new question instead of merging the two together. This allows for better focus, avoids "half" answers and helps searchability.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I created the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check kstenerud github project 
https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework